# Jquery slider displaying wrong on first load

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm having kind of a strange issue with my jquery slideshow. Everything seems to be working fine and I'm not getting any errors, but the slideshow isn't loading right the first time you visit the page. After you refresh the page though everything shows up just fine.

This kind of has me stumped. I thought that maybe I was calling things out of oder, but all I'm doing is calling my jquery in my footer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>inc/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>inc/js/main.js">
```

and all I'm doing in the main is initing the slider.

This is the live site I'm working on. If you go there the first time you can see how it's appearing the first time you visit, because honestly I don't know how to describe what it's doing exactly. http://catlyndesigns.net/home/artwork

Thank you for all your help! :)

Comment: Your link loaded just fine for me the first time.  What browser are you testing with?

Comment: I tested it in both firefox, chrome and safari

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot? Its working fine for me too on first time!!

Comment: here's a link to it on photobucket
http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a485/Jessica_Sears/ScreenShot2013-02-06at35819PM_zpsa44c210d.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! I wasn't assigning heights and widths to the images so the slider was having trouble determining where to place everything. With the added heigh and widths everything works fine! Thank you everyone for all your help!